# rails one base class, two models and two db tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, metaprogramming

I want to create two models with almost identical structures. But I want to keep the data sets in two different tables. Is this possible in active record?

The reason for the different tables is because I want a query that returns no results to be meaningful such as "no active model exists with those properties...", or "no inactive model exists with those properties..."

Also, the classes behave almost identically, so an abstract or base model is important to keep it dry. But I want to be working with clearly named models so that I know I am working with "active" or "inactive" data.

I would imagine the model classes would look something like this, but I am not quite sure how to have models reference different tables. Is this possible?

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :foo, :bar,

end

class ActiveModel < BaseModel
  # This class gets its data from table :active_models

end

class InactiveModel < BaseModel
  # This class gets its data from table :inactive_models

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Base.table_name=](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D) for this.

Alternatively, if your models are appropriately named, you could use `ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix=` or `ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_suffix=`.

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ActiveModel < BaseModel
  # This class gets its data from table :active_models
  self.table_name = 'active_models'
end

class InactiveModel < BaseModel
  # This class gets its data from table :inactive_models
  self.table_name = 'inactive_models'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That is easier than I thought.